# Dynamically change jQuery Mobile navbar contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application using cordova and jquery mobile. in my html page, I have a navbar. I am trying to change the contents of the navbar, which are primarily ui-buttons depending on various situations. For example, when a button is tapped, the navbar should have A, and B buttons or when navigation to a different page occurs, navbar should have C, D and E buttons. I have tried the following code segments:

My Navbar:

```
<div id="navigation" data-role="navbar">
   <div id="bar"> <ul>
        <li>a data-icon="gear" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn" onClick="navSettings();"><h5>Settings</h5></a></li>
    </ul></div>
</div>
```

Trial 1:

```
function onSomeEventA(){
    $("#navigation").attr("data-role","navbar");
            $("#bar").replaceWith('<li><a data-icon="check" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn" onClick="saveSettings();"><h4>Save</h4></a></li><li><a data-icon="delete" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn" onClick="cancel();"><h4>Cancel</h4></a></li>');
}
```

Trial 2:

```
function onSomeEventB(){
    $("#navigation").empty();
    //Add new list
}
```

In both of these situations, i just get a normal list instead of the navbar. Is there any way i can accomplish that?

Comment: A <div> as a child node of a <ul>? First of all you should write clean HTML - only <li> tags are allowed inside of <ul> tags. In your case you can simply give the <ul> tag the id "bar"

Comment: i have edited my post. i had written that by mistake when typing in the code here

Comment: i tried that as well. does not seem to help. same result

Comment: how many buttons you have?

Comment: it depends on what action occurs (which button got clicked)

Comment: you cant modify a created navbar, you need to insert a new one.

Comment: i tried that as well. did not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/N42b9/ it works. if you need more clarification, let me know.